# drupal 7 node multilingual inherited content

Tags: inheritance, drupal-7, multilingual

In the middle of evaluating both Drupal and Joomla. I have figure out how to do the following in Joomla but struggling in Drupal.
So lets say we have 4 sites:

english (/) route

French (/fr)

German (/de)

Japanese (/ja)

Now lets say we have 10 pages on the site total.  All of the pages exist in the English site (the route)
I then only want to translate a select few into different languages. 
This is made easy with the translate button that i can create another version of the page.

Now on top of this. If a page does not exist in one of the international sites (meaning i did not translate the page into a different language) I would like it to pull in the english content but still load the /fr /ger or /jp site.

Let me know if i need to clarify more.

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I swear language neutral was not working for me ealier. NOW IT IS. 
creating the english or default site in language neutral solves this issue.

Thanks

City

Comment: Although, When i have a node set to language neutral it will not allow me to make a translation of another language. It just errors and says it already exists. I would literally have to unselect language neutral create a new translation in one of the languages and then re-select language neutral...